# Implementing iterator operator* for container storing values on disk

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

In my container I use special functions to get/set (MyGet/MySet) my piece of data (TData). How do I implement operator* for output iterator?

I can manage it for input:

```
const TData& operator *() const{
            return this->MyGet(this->index);
}
```

But how do I call MySet in output?

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate the disk aspect. What does `MySet` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `TData` by reference, return some new class `TDataProxy` by value. Create `operator TData` and `operator=(TData)` in it and you will be able to control when `MySet` call is needed.